# UrlFetchApp with Service Account credentials in Google script throws errors with post, put, patch

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, service-accounts

I have a private test spreadsheet that is shared to the Service Account email for a GAS project. Below is:

1. A function to "get" data from that spreadsheet using UrlFetchApp with Service Account oAuth2 credentials.  (Fetch has Range value:  "'sName'!A1:B3"; sheet has Row 1 column headings: A - "uId";  B - "title").  It works fine with the spreadsheet shared (with edit rights) to the Service Account email.  It fails for lack of authorization without that share.  So, the oAuth credentials *seem* to be correct, with Scope of spreadsheets. (I'm working with [this code](https://github.com/Spencer-Easton/Apps-Script-GSApp-Library/blob/4d0044827e5c979e05d61306824a91214475d5a5/GSApp.gs#L84) by Spencer Easton to generate the oAuth clientToken for the service account.)
2. A function for updating (post, put, patch) the same test spreadsheet. It fails with all three methods, but with different error messages as follows:

*Put*: "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "title": Cannot bind query parameter. Field 'title' could not be found in request message." If contentType:'application/json' is included in options, the error changes to: "Invalid JSON payload received. Unexpected token.\nuId=id3&title=Update\n^"
(fetch updateRange value: "'sName'!A3:B3" or "'sName'!A4:B4")

*Post*:  "The requested URL `/v4/spreadsheets/[actual ssId]/values/'sName'!A4:B4` was not found on this server. That’s all we know."

*Patch*: same as Post, with updateRange= "'sName'!A3:B3"

I've gone through SO Q&A postings related to these errors.  Some say the problem is including contentType in the options (or Content-Type: in the headers).  That didn't fix things, but does change the error message with "put" method, as stated above. Google UrlFetchApp docs say it is not needed for updates (so below it is shown commented out).

I hope I'm just overlooking something basic in properly configuring the range or the options for updates using UrlFetchApp.

Thank you for any guidance in resolving this problem with updating.

1. GET DATA -- Correctly retrieves data

```
function getData(ssId,range) {
   if (!clientToken) { return "Authorization Failed";}
      var url= `https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/${ssId}/values/${range}`
      var options = {
             method:  'get',    
             contentType: 'application/json',
         headers: { Authorization: 'Bearer ' + clientToken }
          };
      response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,options);
      return response;
    
 } //end getData function
 var fetchData = getData(ssId,range);
```

2. UPDATE DATA -- errors for post, put and patch

The update data object: var updateData = {'uId':'id3', 'title':'Update Title'}

```
function postData(ssId,updateRange,updateData) {
    if (!clientToken) {return "Authorization Failed";}
    var url= `https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/${ssId}/values/${updateRange}`
        var options = {
    //           contentType: 'application/json',  
             valueInputOption: 'RAW',
             method:   'put',     //patch, post, or put 
             payload: updateData,     
             headers: { Authorization: 'Bearer ' + clientToken }
             };
     var response= UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,options);
     var responseCode = response.getResponseCode();
     var responseBody = response.getContentText();
    if (responseCode === 200) {
                var responseJson = JSON.parse(responseBody);
                return responseJson; 
      } else {
             Logger.log(Utilities.formatString("Request failed. Expected 200, got %d: %s", responseCode, responseBody))
                 return responseCode;
                 }      
   } //end postData function
 var dataUpdate = postData(ssId,updateRange,updateData);
```

Comment: I don't see where you are specifying the scopes for these requests. Could you share your entire code (removing sensitive data but making a reference as to what needs to be put in place) so that anybody that can help can take a look and reproduce without having to do extra configuration work?

Comment: @Yancy Melany -- thanks so much for responding to my question.  I left out the authorization specifics (only mentioning Scope for the token is "spreadsheets") because I have been warned (and given a -1 score) for having multi-part questions.  I focused question on the fetch configuration and errors.  As you see, Tanaike also replied & his solution works.  My follow-up question to him is why the fetch(url,params) doc shows the payload config that I used, but that fails! Thanks again--these responses are so important for us with limited GAS experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, I cannot confirm the method you want to use in your 2nd script. But, from your endpoint, I guessed that you might have wanted to "Method: spreadsheets.values.update". [Ref](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/update)

If my understanding is correct,

- `var updateData = {'uId':'id3', 'title':'Update Title'}` cannot be directly used in this method.
- There is not property of `valueInputOption` in `UrlFetchApp.fetch()`.

If the header row has `uId` and `title` in the columns "A" and "B" and you want to put the values of `id3` and `Update Title` to `updateRange`, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
var url= `https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/${ssId}/values/${updateRange}`
    var options = {
//           contentType: 'application/json',  
         valueInputOption: 'RAW',
         method:   'put',     //patch, post, or put 
         payload: updateData,     
         headers: { Authorization: 'Bearer ' + clientToken }
         };
```

#### To:

```
// var updateData = [['uId', 'title'], ['id3', 'Update Title']]; // If you want to include the header row, please use this.
var updateData = {values: [['id3', 'Update Title']]};

var url = `https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/${ssId}/values/${updateRange}?valueInputOption=RAW`;
var options = {
  contentType: 'application/json',
  method: 'put',
  payload: JSON.stringify(updateData),
  headers: { Authorization: 'Bearer ' + clientToken }
};
```

#### Note:

- I think that if your access token can be used for putting values to Google Spreadsheet, this modified script works.

#### References:

- [Method: spreadsheets.values.update](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/update)
- [fetch(url, params)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl,-params)

Comment: @Tanaike--Yes! your rewrite works for "put" method! (post and patch do not work; data specification with headers also does not work).  I see that the range can be bigger than the saved content, non-contiguous cells can be updated by not entering content for the cells to remain unchanged, multiple rows can be added in same fetch.  My remaining question is why the fetch(url,params) documentation examples (which I followed) show using form object format (that fails) instead of the Google nested arrays . Where do I find docs about the nested arrays with UrlFetchApp? Thank you!!

Comment: since form object cannot be used directly, is there a standard utility for converting form object data into the Google nested arrays?  Or is it up to everyone to recreate that routine?  Thanks again.

Comment: @DougMS Thank you for replying. About `values` in the request body, you can see it at [this official document](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values#ValueRange). In the above modification, `majorDimension` is used as the default value of `ROWS`.

Comment: Thank you for reference to spreadsheets.values.update method, but I don't understand that REST methods are applicable with UrlFetchApp.  For example, I don't see that your RangeListApp library is applicable to UrlFetchApp.  Can a range list be used with "get" method in UrlFetchApp fetch?

Comment: @DougMS Thank you for replying. I would like to support your new question. But I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `Thank you for reference to spreadsheets.values.update method, but I don't understand that REST methods are applicable with UrlFetchApp. For example, I don't see that your RangeListApp library is applicable to UrlFetchApp. Can a range list be used with "get" method in UrlFetchApp fetch?`. Can I ask you about the detail of your new question?