# Error in Google webapp using URLFetchApp: range exceeds grid limits when inserting new row

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, urlfetch

With great [SO help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71430537/urlfetchapp-with-service-account-credentials-in-google-script-throws-errors-with/71432252#71432252) at previous step, I have writes to sheet almost working with URLFetchApp under service account credentials in a webapp. The code (below) only works with the "put" method; "post" generates an error.  My understanding is that updates and inserts can both be done with "put" method.  But the code is generating an error when the range is for a new row--that is, the last row in the sheet is not blank.

"range exceeds grid limits when inserting new row"

If it is necessary to have empty rows (e.g., add 1000 rows), does this become a manual maintenance job to monitor and periodically add new blank rows?  I expected the "put" to simply add a new row.  Is there another method with URLFetchApp to first add rows to the "grid" before inserting data?  Thank you for any guidance!

```
function postData(ssID,updateRange,data) {
    if (clientToken) {
     var url= `https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/${ssID}/values/${updateRange}?valueInputOption=RAW`
     var options = {
        muteHttpExceptions: true,
        contentType: 'application/json',
        method:'put', 
        payload: JSON.stringify(data),
        headers: { Authorization: 'Bearer ' + clientToken }
        };
    var response= UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,options);
     var responseCode = response.getResponseCode();
     var responseBody = response.getContentText();
        if (responseCode === 200) {
             var responseJson = JSON.parse(responseBody)
               return responseJson;
          } else {
          Logger.log(Utilities.formatString("Request failed. Expected 200, got %d: %s", responseCode, responseBody))
            return responseCode;
          }
      }  else {//handle failed authorization }
      
   } //end postData
```

Comment: From your question, I understand that you are required to use Sheets API with the access token retrieved by the service account. For example, as a workaround, in your situation, when your Google account is shared with the Spreadsheet of the service account, you can use the Spreadsheet service (SpreadsheetApp). By this, I thought that the script can become simpler. How about this? But, if in your situation, you cannot do it, don't worry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no method in the **Sheets API V4** that can automatically add rows when the given range exceeds the sheet range.

What you can do is to get the **rowCount** of a specific sheet by using [Method: spreadsheets.get](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/get) then compare it with the range you will use to update values. If **rowCount** is less than the update range, use [Method: spreadsheets.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate) to update the sheet dimension.

### Demo:

**Example Sheet:**

[image]

**Code:**

```
function request(ssID="spreadsheet id here",updateRange = "A1499:A1500",data) {
  if (clientToken) {
    var ssGetUrl= `https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/${ssID}`
    var options = {
        muteHttpExceptions: true,
        contentType: 'application/json',
        method:'get', 
        headers: { Authorization: 'Bearer ' + clientToken }
        };
    var ssGetresponse= JSON.parse(UrlFetchApp.fetch(ssGetUrl,options));
    var sheets = ssGetresponse.sheets;
    var rowCount = 0;
    var sheetId = 0;
    sheets.forEach(sheet => {
      if(sheet.properties.sheetId == sheetId){
        rowCount = sheet.properties.gridProperties.rowCount
      }
    })
    var num = parseInt(updateRange.split(":")[1].replace(/[^0-9]/g,'')); //remove letters in updateRange and convert it to string
    if(rowCount < num){
      var diff = num - rowCount;
      var resource = {
          "requests": [
            {
              "appendDimension": {
                "length": diff,
                "dimension": "ROWS",
                "sheetId": 0
              }
            }
          ]
        };
      var ssBatchUpdateUrl= `https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/${ssID}:batchUpdate`
      var options = {
          muteHttpExceptions: true,
          contentType: 'application/json',
          method:'post',
          payload: JSON.stringify(resource), 
          headers: { Authorization: 'Bearer ' + clientToken }
          };
      var response= JSON.parse(UrlFetchApp.fetch(ssBatchUpdateUrl,options));
    }
    //insert code for updating range values
  }
}
```

**After executing code:**

[image]

**Note:** The demo above is for increasing the number of rows when the update range is beyond the sheet's actual rows. For instance, if you have a range that the column is beyond the sheet's actual column, you can update the script to also read the **columnCount**, modify the parser to also get column part of A1 Notation and add another entry on `appendDimension` with **COLUMN** as dimension.

Comment: I thought that your approach is the correct direction. From `I have writes to sheet almost working with URLFetchApp under service account credentials`, I thought that in OP's situation, it is required to use Sheets API with access token retrieved from service account. In this case, I think that Sheets API cannot be used with Advanced Google services. Because Advanced Google services cannot set the access token. In this situation, how about modifying your script for directly requesting to the endpoint with UrlFetchApp? And also, OP's `updateRange` might be A1Notation including the sheet name.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I think that your answer will be useful for not only OP but also other users.

Comment: Thank you, Nikko and @Tanaike!  Pls confirm:  I replace // insert code comment line at end of your "request" function with my "postData" code (adjusting for difference in "updateRange")--correct?  Also, why in "var resource ... requests" is sheetId = 0 ? Shouldn't it be the sheetId of my  "updateRange" ("'sheetName'!A1-update-range")?  I can pass the sheetId  and the number of rows to add to grid (usually 1) for the "diff" value --  that would streamline your code to only the fetch "post" with ssBatchUpdateUrl--correct?

Comment: Nikko and @Tanaike--a follow-up question:  UrlFetchApp has batch fetchAll(requests) method.  Can the batchUpdate fetch (Req1: to add rows to grid) and then the updateData fetch (Req2: to insert the data) be executed in proper sequence with a single fetchAll([{Req1},{Req2}]) ?

Comment: @DougMS - **1.** Yes **2.** sheetID 0 is the default sheet id of the first sheet when you create a  new spreadsheet. **3.** I used sheet id 0 just to show you how to resolve the issue of `updateRange is beyond the sheets actual range`. You can modify it to get the sheet id by using [Method: spreadsheets.get](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/get) **4.** Yes you can do that. Again, the demo is for you to have insights on how to resolve the problem. You can always modify it depending on your script needs.

Comment: Thank you again, Nikko.  Regarding the last (#5) follow-up question--I was just concerned whether submitting the grid addition and the data submission together in the FetchAll method might be vulnerable to async/timing problems where the grid addition would not complete before the data submission.

Comment: @DougMS - Apologies, I forgot that the URL for Method: spreadsheets.batchUpdate(which I used for updating row count) is different from Method: spreadsheets.values.batchUpdate(For updating values in sheets). You have to create another request for updating cell value.

Answer (score 0):

#### Try this:

```
function postData(ssID, updateRange, data) {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssID);
  const sh = ss.getRange(updateRange).getSheet();//I assumed range is in A1 notation
  const lr = sh.getLastRow();
  if (lr == sh.getMaxRows()) {
    sh.insertRowsAfter(lr, data.length);
  }
  if (clientToken) {
    var url = `https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/${ssID}/values/${updateRange}?valueInputOption=RAW`
    var options = {
      muteHttpExceptions: true,
      contentType: 'application/json',
      method: 'put',
      payload: JSON.stringify(data),
      headers: { Authorization: 'Bearer ' + clientToken }
    };
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
    var responseCode = response.getResponseCode();
    var responseBody = response.getContentText();
    if (responseCode === 200) {
      var responseJson = JSON.parse(responseBody)
      return responseJson;
    } else {
      Logger.log(Utilities.formatString("Request failed. Expected 200, got %d: %s", responseCode, responseBody))
      return responseCode;
    }
  } else {//handle failed authorization }

  } //end postData
```